# Replacing do-while loops as convergence query in Fortran OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, do-while, convergence

I have build a program that uses Differential Evolution to optimize atom positions in regard to their pair-wise potential and now want to parallelize it with OpenMP to which I am quite new. The Differential Evolution uses an overall do-while loop in which a convergence query is used as the exit condition.

That means

1. I know that I can not simply `!$OMP PARALLEL DO` the do-while loop
2. I can not predict at what point the loop is terminated
3. following iterations would also meet the condition. The following is
   my unparallelized code:

   ```
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15, 307)
   real(kind = dp) :: sum_dif, sum, sum_old, final_toler, F, CR, d1, d2, d3, max_step, this_step, scale, randomtest
   integer :: pop, dim, arfa, beta, gama, delt, bi, jrand, kf, ki, kj, kg, dim_low, i, g, num_Ti, idum
   logical :: monitor_progress, history
   integer, dimension(0:) :: index
   real(kind=dp), dimension(0:,0:) :: depop, tempop 
   real(kind=dp), dimension(0:) :: best,temp_best, proj, d_fx, t_fx
   real(kind=dp) :: midpoint
   logical :: best_DE, use_maxstep
   integer*2 :: best_DE_num

   sum_dif = 0.0
   do while ((abs(sum_old - sum + sum_dif)) > final_toler) !UTILIZE DIFFERENTIAL EVOLUTION until convergence
       ! ↑ enclosing convergence loop
       sum_old = sum
       !**initialize DE-Parameters**
       if (best_DE) then
           F = 0.2_dp + 0.6_dp * ran2(idum)
           CR = 0.6_dp + 0.4_dp * ran2(idum)
       else
           F = 0.4_dp + 0.4_dp * ran2(idum)
           CR = 0.7_dp + 0.2_dp * ran2(idum)
       end if
       !******
       !** Create Mutant Population AND Perform Population Update**
       do i = 0, pop - 1
           do
               arfa = RNGgen(pop)
               if (arfa /= i) exit
           end do
           do
               beta = RNGgen(pop)
               if (beta /= arfa) then
                   if (beta /= i) exit
               end if
           end do
           do
               gama = RNGgen(pop)
               if (gama /= beta) then
                   if (gama /= arfa) then
                       if (gama /= i) exit
                   end if
               end if
           end do
           do
               delt = RNGgen(pop)
               if (delt /= gama) then
                   if (delt /= beta) then
                       if (delt /= arfa) then
                           if (delt /= i) exit !loops will be continued until arfa!=beta!=gama!=delt!=i
                       end if
                   end if
               end if
           end do
           jrand = RNGgen(dim + 1)/3 
           !**Create mutant population per atom not per dim
           kf = 0

           do while (kf < dim)
               randomtest = ran2(idum)
               if ((randomtest <= CR).or.(kf == jrand)) then 
                   !**Create hybrid child**
               d1 = F * (depop(arfa, kf) - depop(gama, kf) + best_DE_num * (depop(beta, kf) - depop(delt, kf)))
               d2 = F * (depop(arfa, kf + 1) - depop(gama, kf + 1) + best_DE_num * (depop(beta, kf + 1) - depop(delt, kf + 1)))
               d3 = F * (depop(arfa, kf + 2) - depop(gama, kf + 2) + best_DE_num * (depop(beta, kf + 2) - depop(delt, kf + 2)))
                   !******
                   if (use_maxstep) then
                       this_step = d1 * d1 + d2 * d2 + d3 * d3!norm^2
                       if (this_step > max_step) then
                           scale = sqrt(max_step/this_step)
                           d1 = d1 * scale
                           d2 = d2 * scale
                           d3 = d3 * scale
                       end if
                   end if !end if use_maxstep
                   tempop(i, kf) = best_DE_num * best(kf)+(1 - best_DE_num) * depop(beta, kf) + d1
                   tempop(i, kf + 1) = best_DE_num * best(kf + 1)+(1 - best_DE_num) * depop(beta, kf + 1) + d2
                   tempop(i, kf + 2) = best_DE_num * best(kf + 2)+(1 - best_DE_num) * depop(beta, kf + 2) + d3
               else
                   tempop(i, kf) = depop(i, kf)
                   tempop(i, kf + 1) = depop(i, kf + 1)
                   tempop(i, kf + 2) = depop(i, kf + 2)
               end if
               kf = kf + 3
           end do !end dim do loop
           !******
           call trans_to_cent(tempop(i,:), midpoint, midpoint, midpoint, 0, dim_low)
           !******
           !**Evaluate Objective Function for Mutant
           tempop(i, dim) = Analytic_U(num_Ti, tempop(i,:))
           t_fx(i) = tempop(i, dim) !store tempop fx values
           !******
       end do !end pop do loop
       do i = 0, pop - 1
           d_fx(i) = depop(i, dim) !store depop fx values
       end do
       !******
       !**SORTED MUTANT REPLACEMENT**
       index = Max_DelF(d_fx, t_fx)
       do kg = 0, pop - 1
           if (tempop(index(kg), dim) < depop(kg, dim)) then
               depop(kg,:) = tempop(index(kg),:)
           end if
           d_fx(kg) = depop(kg, dim) 
       end do
       !******
       !**Obtain total cost function values for tolerance comparison**
       sum = 0
       do ki = 0, pop - 1
           sum = sum + depop(ki, dim)
       end do
       sum = sum/pop !calculate average energy value            
       !******
       !**Obtain global best**
       do kj = 0, pop - 1
           if (best(dim) > depop(kj, dim)) then
               best = depop(kj,:)
               bi = kj
           end if !determine "best" vector
       end do
       !******
       if (monitor_progress) then
           print*, "Progress (min = 1.0): ", (abs(sum_old - sum + sum_dif))/final_toler
       end if
       g = g + 1 !increment iteration counter
   end do !end generation (while) loop
   ```

Here, the loop on the top is the one in question. The exit condition triggers when the energy difference from one iteration to the next one is below a certain threshold. The code includes several other do-loops inside of this one but they should be parallelizable without major problems.

My question now is: can the enclosing loop be parallelized without giving up most of the performance boost or will there be still a boost if I try to exclude it from the parallel region?

If I do that I also could exclude the generation of mutant population variables `arfa, beta, gama, delt` because their generation would have to be done with `!$OMP CRITICAL` with a considerable overhead anyway since they are randomly build with `arfa!=beta!=gama!=delt!`, right? I am using the `random_number` intrinsic with random seeds in my `RNGgen` function. My compiler is gfortran.

Comment: The outer loop is clearly not parallelizable anyway! Consider your own statement "The exit condition triggers when the energy difference from one iteration to the next one is below a certain threshold." that implies that the loop iterations are executed in order (so that you can compare the energy computed at iteration N with that at iteration N-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided was not complete: it did not compile. I decided to construct a small
(complete) program that does something which I think is similar. I hope it helps!

The program starts up a parallell session, in which new populations are found.
Whenever a better population is found than the best so far, the best population
is updated. The iteration stops when the global calculation spends too many iterations
between consecutive improvements.

In this program, every next population is constructed completely from scratch.
In your program, there is a more advanced generation of the next population. favoring
'better' populations over 'worse' ones.

In a naive parallallization, each thread will follow its own path through the search
space, and it will not 'learn' from what the other threads have found out.
To exchange search information between threads, you need to design a method and then
program it. To do so seemed outside of the scope of this question.

Here comes the program:

```
program optimize_population
use Population ! contains the target function
use omp_lib
implicit none
    integer, parameter :: really_long = 100000
    real(kind=dp) :: best, targetFun
    real(kind=dp) :: pop(2,npop), best_pop(2,npop)
    integer, allocatable :: iter(:)
    integer :: i, nt, it, ierr, last_improvement 

    call initTarget()  ! initialize the target function

    ! Allocate an iteration count for every thread
    nt = omp_get_max_threads()
    allocate(iter(nt), stat=ierr)
    if (ierr/=0) stop('allocation error')
    iter = 0


    best = -1e10
    last_improvement = 0

!$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(it, pop, i, targetFun)
      it = omp_get_thread_num()+1  ! thread number
      do
          iter(it) = iter(it) + 1

          ! Create a new population
          do i = 1,npop
             pop(1,i) = rand()
             pop(2,i) = rand()
          end do

          ! Evaluate target function  
          targetFun = popFun(pop)

          if (targetFun>best) then
          ! If this is the best population so far,
          !    then register this

!$OMP          CRITICAL
                  best_pop = pop
                  best = targetFun
                  print '(a,i0,a,i7,a,1p,e13.5)', '[',it,'] iteration ',sum(iter),' Best score until now: ',TargetFun
                  last_improvement = sum(iter) ! remember the global iteration count for the last time an improved population was found
!$OMP          END CRITICAL
          end if

          ! Done when further improvement takes too long
          if (last_improvement < sum(iter) - really_long) exit
      end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL

    ! Report the best population found
    targetFun = popFun(best_pop)
    print '(a,1p,e13.5)', 'Best score found: ',targetFun
    print '(a,1p,e13.5)', '    best population found:'
    do i = 1,npop
       print '(1p,10(a,e13.5))', '    (',best_pop(1,i),',',best_pop(2,i),')'
    end do

end program  optimize_population
```

The program needs the target-function, which is provided by the module Population, below:

```
module Population
integer, parameter :: npop  = 20, ncenter = 3
integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1d0)
real(kind=dp)      :: center(2,ncenter)
contains

    subroutine initTarget()
    implicit none
       integer :: i
       do i = 1,ncenter
          center(1,i) = rand()
          center(2,i) = rand()
       end do
       print '(a,i0,a)', &
          'Looking for a population of ',npop,' points in the unit square,'
       print '(a,i0,a)', &
          'equally spread out in space, but clustered around the points'
       print '(1p,10(a,e13.5))', &
          '    (',center(1,1),',',center(2,1), &
          ('),    (',center(1,i),',',center(2,i), i=2,ncenter-1), &
          ')    and (',center(1,ncenter),',',center(2,ncenter),')'
    end subroutine initTarget


    function popFun(pop) result(targetFun)
    implicit none
        real(kind=dp), intent(in) :: pop(:,:)
        real(kind=dp) :: targetFun

        integer :: i,j
        real(kind=dp) :: sum_center, sum_dist

        sum_dist = 0
        sum_center = 0
        do i = 1,npop
           do j = i+1,npop
              sum_dist   = sum_dist + (pop(1,i)-pop(1,j))**2 + (pop(2,i)-pop(2,j))**2
           end do
           do j = 1,ncenter
              sum_center = sum_center + (pop(1,i)-center(1,j))**2 + (pop(2,i)-center(2,j))**2
           end do
        end do

        targetFun = sum_dist - sum_center
    end function popFun

end module Population
```

Comment: Thank you Nathan! The most important idea for me in your answer is the concept of an iteration array whose sum triggers the exit condition. By that I should at least be able to circumvent the convergence problem.